# Formatting cite to: author [ref]

Tags: bibtex, formatting, citing

I am doing citations like `\cite{waseem16}` where it appears like: Waseem and Hovy [2016].

But I want to make it appear like: Wassem and Hovy[WH16].

How do I format my citation to appear like so?
Thanks

```
\usepackage{natbib} 
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

% bibliography is in ``myrefs.bib''
\PrintBib{myrefs}

\newcommand{\PrintBib}[1]{%
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Refer\^{e}ncias}%
\if@numericrefs%
  \bibliographystyle{unsrt-pt}%
\else%
  \if@alpharefs%
    \bibliographystyle{alpha-pt}%
  \else%
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat-pt}%
  \fi%
\fi%
\cleardoublepage%
\phantomsection%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Refer\^{e}ncias}%
\begin{singlespace}\bibliography{#1}\end{singlespace}}
```

The follwing code are just the few fist lines of painnat-pt file:

```
ENTRY
  { address
    author
    booktitle
    chapter
    doi
    eid
    edition
    editor
    howpublished
    institution
    isbn
    issn
    journal
    key
    month
    note
    number
    organization
    pages
    publisher
    school
    series
    title
    type
    url
    volume
    year
  }
  {}
  { label extra.label sort.label short.list }

INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block }

FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
{ #0 'before.all :=
  #1 'mid.sentence :=
  #2 'after.sentence :=
  #3 'after.block :=
}
```

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) where does `\PrintBib` come from? Never seen that before. Please provide a full but minimal example instead of a sniplet like this. Basically provide something others can copy and use as is in order to test whatever issue you are having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit `abbrvnat.bst` to be some sort of a mix between `alpha` and `abbrv`. Save the resulting file as `alphanat.bst`. Note that this is only a proof of concept, it works for the MWE but it may break at any point.

The modifications to `abbrvnat.bst` are as follows.

1. Copy the function `format.lab.names` (the label formatting function) and a few lines above that, unmodified, to `alphanat.bst` and rename the function to `format.lab.alphanames`:

```
INTEGERS { et.al.char.used }

FUNCTION {initialize.et.al.char.used}
{ #0 'et.al.char.used :=
}

EXECUTE {initialize.et.al.char.used}

FUNCTION {format.lab.alphanames}
{ 's :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames #1 >
    { numnames #4 >
        { #3 'namesleft := }
        { numnames 'namesleft := }
      if$
      #1 'nameptr :=
      ""
        { namesleft #0 > }
        { nameptr numnames =
            { s nameptr "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
                { "{\etalchar{+}}" *
                  #1 'et.al.char.used :=
                }
                { s nameptr "{v{}}{l{}}" format.name$ * }
              if$
            }
            { s nameptr "{v{}}{l{}}" format.name$ * }
          if$
          nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
          namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
        }
      while$
      numnames #4 >
        { "{\etalchar{+}}" *
          #1 'et.al.char.used :=
        }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
    { s #1 "{v{}}{l{}}" format.name$
      duplicate$ text.length$ #2 <
        { pop$ s #1 "{ll}" format.name$ #3 text.prefix$ }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

2. Change the function `author.key.label` to concatenate the output of the regular label formatting, an open parentheses, and the output of the function copied from `alpha.bst`:

```
FUNCTION {author.key.label}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
        { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
        'key
      if$
    }
    { author format.lab.names "(" * author format.lab.alphanames * }
  if$
}
```

3. In the comments it was noted that there was an issue with a different `.bib` file, it turned out that the solution did not work for `@book` entries. These entries call the function `author.editor.key.label` instead of `author.key.label`. Therefore that function should be adapted as well, similar to the modification to `author.key.label`:

```
FUNCTION {author.editor.key.label}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
        { key empty$
            { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
            'key
          if$
        }
        { editor format.lab.names "(" * editor format.lab.alphanames * }
      if$
    }
    { author format.lab.names "(" * author format.lab.alphanames * }
  if$
}
```

Note that the functions `author.key.organization.label` and `editor.key.organization.label` should also be modified accordingly for entries where organizations are involved.

4. Modify the function `calc.label` in order to remove the parenthesis and to print only the last two digits of the year:

```
FUNCTION {calc.label}
{ calc.short.authors
  short.list
  year #-1 #2 substring$ duplicate$ empty$
  short.list key field.or.null = or
     { pop$ "" }
     'skip$
  if$
  *
  'label :=
}
```

Finally, load `natbib` with the option `square` to get square brackets, and load the new `alphanat` style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{alphanat}
\begin{document}
See \cite{waseem16}.

\bibliography{myrefs}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Edit: Of course it is nice if the `alpha` key is also shown in the bibliography itself. To do that, you should copy a slightly modified version of the `format.lab.alphanames` function somewhere above the `format.authors` function around line 250 (so the modified function is defined when `format.authors` needs it):

```
FUNCTION {format.lab.anames}
{ 's :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames #1 >
    { numnames #4 >
        { #3 'namesleft := }
        { numnames 'namesleft := }
      if$
      #1 'nameptr :=
      ""
        { namesleft #0 > }
        { nameptr numnames =
            { s nameptr "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
                { "+" * }
                { s nameptr "{v{}}{l{}}" format.name$ * }
              if$
            }
            { s nameptr "{v{}}{l{}}" format.name$ * }
          if$
          nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
          namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
        }
      while$
      numnames #4 >
        { "+" * }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
    { s #1 "{v{}}{l{}}" format.name$
      duplicate$ text.length$ #2 <
        { pop$ s #1 "{ll}" format.name$ #3 text.prefix$ }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

The difference to `format.lab.alphanames` is that the symbol for more than 4 authors (`+`) is hardcoded.

Then you can modify `format.authors` to use the label and the year:

```
FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author empty$
    { "" }
    { "[" author format.lab.anames * year #-1 #2 substring$ * "] " * author format.names * }
  if$
}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that this would be *much* easier with BibLaTeX - but with BibTeX the question is more interesting :)

Comment: I think I done the intructions as you said, but I only have the citation as: [1], [2], etc.
Could you link using pastebin your version of the .bst please?

Comment: @user190963 it's here: https://pastebin.com/jxNAruRM - note that you also need to specify the bibliographystyle in your `.tex` file.

Comment: Stange, now I'm getting the citation like this: [Waseem and Hovy(WH16)Waseem and Hovy]

Comment: Did you try with the MWE or with your own `.tex` file?

Comment: I used it in my .tex, like this \bibliographystyle{alphanat}

Comment: And what happens when you try the `.tex` file from my answer, without any modifications (with `pdflatex`), with a `.bib` file containing only the `waseem16` entry and nothing else? If that works then there is something in your file that modifies the behavior, otherwise the problem might be how you apply the solution, where you store your files, etc. Or maybe you did not remove all auxiliary files before trying the solution?

Comment: Yes, it was some conditions  that were setting other styles, Thanks, problem solved!!

Comment: @Marijn: Thanks a lot for the effort and for providing that solution. However, when I try your MWE, I get `ERROR: Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.` I've used your file from pastebin in the same directory as the MWE, with a bibfile only containing a fake waseem16 entry. Getting the same error with my own Latex document and my own bibfile, btw.

Comment: @Mario strange, that error is intended for a different situation. If you want we can discuss the issue in chat (https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/110782/discussion-between-marijn-and-mario?tab=general).