# Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations (again!)

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am trying to cite the following

```
@article{ghahramani2015probabilistic,
title={Probabilistic machine learning and artificial intelligence},
author={Ghahramani, Zoubin},
journal={Nature},
volume={521},
number={7553},
pages={452--459},
year={2015},
publisher={Nature Publishing Group}
}
```

with

```
\citet{ghahramani2015probabilistic}
```

But I keep getting the error

> Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.

But that citation contains a year and an author. I am importing `natbib` with the `square` option, and using `\bibliographystyle{alpha}`.  Any idea?

I already removed all files and compiled everything again, but I get the same error.

I am compiling with

```
"pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|"bibtex" %.aux|"pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|"pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

which I have a template that I always used to compile bibliographies.

Answer (score 4):

To extract the author and the year for a citation, `natbib` needs a bibliography entry (in the bbl) which starts like this:

```
\bibitem[Ghahramani(2015)]{ghahramani2015probabilistic}
```

The important part is the syntax of the optional argument `[Ghahramani(2015)]`. natbib scans this and splits it in author and year.

With `\bibliographystyle{alpha}` the entry looks like this:

```
\bibitem[Gha15]{ghahramani2015probabilistic}
```

This is unusable for natbib, there is no year or author it can extract.

If you want to use natbib you should use a compatible style like e.g. plainnat instead of alpha. If you want an alpha style you could try to create your own bst with https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/495642/2388.
Or you can switch to biblatex and biber which supports more styles.

Comment: Ohh, beaten again by 45 seconds. What surprised me was that at least on my machine I didn't get the error from `alpha` that I expected and it turns out `natbib` checks the style name and automatically forces `numbers` when it sees `\bibliographystyle{alpha}`, but that is overridden by the `square` option used by the OP.

Comment: @moewe I didn't really check under which conditions it errors or warns as there was no real example.  The main point imho is anyway to understand that not every style works with natbib.

Comment: Absolutely, that's the main point. I was just confused because in a short MWE I made up for my answer I couldn't reproduce the error with `\bibliographstyle{alpha}` - and now I'm just impressed by how clever `natbib` is.

Comment: you should not use it. It is created by bibtex. Look in the bbl-file.

Answer (score 3):

The error message

> ```
> Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.
> ```

has two major causes:

- Either it can be taken at face value and then says that the bibliography style you used is incompatible with `natbib`'s `authoryear` citation option
- or the style you use is in principle compatible with `natbib`'s `authoryear` citation option, but certain entries are missing `author`/`editor` or `year` fields.

All that is due to the way author-year citations are implemented in `natbib`. The usual bibliography that is created by BibTeX is essentially a glorified `enumerate` environment and `\cite` works just like a `\ref` to a `\label` (you can read more about this at [A design question: citation commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/473471/35864)). In order to be able to produce flexible author-year citations `natbib` uses a clever way to make the author and year known in the document. But that means that the bibliography created by BibTeX must have a particular format, this is explained in a code comment in `natbib.sty`

```
 % If author-year citations are selected, \bibitem must have one of the
 %   following forms:
 %   \bibitem[Jones et al.(1990)]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[Jones et al.(1990)Jones, Baker, and Williams]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[Jones et al., 1990]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Jones, Baker, and Williams}{Jones
 %       et al.}{1990}]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Jones et al.}{1990}]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[\protect\astroncite{Jones et al.}{1990}]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[\protect\citename{Jones et al., }1990]{key}...
 %   \harvarditem[Jones et al.]{Jones, Baker, and Williams}{1990}{key}...
```

You can only get author-year citations if your `\bibliographystyle` produces `\bibitem`s looking like this. Not all styles are compatible with this format.

If author or year fields are missing, even styles that are in principle compatible with this format can produce a `\bibitem` that can not be parsed by `natbib` according to the above specification. In that case you will also get this error.

A 'solution' that works for both problems is to forget about author-year citations and tell `natbib` to use numeric citations by loading it with the `numbers` option. Then `natbib` does not try to extract author-year data for normal citations. `\citet` may still not work as desired though. So it is somewhat pointless to use `natbib` with an incompatible style.

If the style is incompatible the other straightforward solution is to choose a compatible style. The `natbib` styles `plainnat`, `abbrvnat`, `unsrtnat` are obviously a good `natbib` compatible choice, but there are many more styles out there that work.

If the problem is just caused by your entry missing `author`/`editor` or `year` fields, the obvious solution is to try and supply these fields. If that is not possible you may get a slightly better result if you add placeholder values for those fields. Like `author = {N.N.},` and `year = {n.d.},`

---

`natbib` has a very clever method to avoid this kind of error for some common styles: If you just load `natbib` without any additional citation style options `\usepackage{natbib}` some styles automatically force the `numbers` option without you explicitly setting it and even if you have passed the `authoryear` option. But that method is disabled when you use the citation style option  `square`.

Compare the following MWE with and without the `square` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ghahramani2015probabilistic,
  title   = {Probabilistic machine learning and artificial intelligence},
  author  = {Ghahramani, Zoubin},
  journal = {Nature},
  volume  = {521},
  number  = {7553},
  pages   = {452--459},
  year    = {2015},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\citep{ghahramani2015probabilistic}
\citet{ghahramani2015probabilistic}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the options `numbers` while importing `natbib` and now I don't get the error anymore. Not sure why though.