# biblatex showing shortcut names in text instead of author(year)

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, formatting, citing, natbib

I'm using a dissertation template from my university (don't know everything going on under the hood) and I'm having a hell of a time with the citations.

Basically, **the compiled document shows the shortcut name in the text where the citation should be.** So for example, if I have

`\bibitem[Einstein(1915)]{GR_paper} Einstein, A. 1915. General Relativity.`

and in the text I write *"In \citealt{GR_paper}, we find..."*

The text shows up as "In **[GR_paper]**, we find..."

Note that this happens whether I use `\citep{}`, `\citet{}`, `\citealt{}`, whatever. The citations themselves at the end of the chapter also look a bit funky. They'll show up as

*[Einstein(1915)] Einstein, A. 1915. General Relativity.*

I want the citation to appear as *Einstein (1915)* for `\citealt` and *(Einstein 1915)* for `\citep.`

Relevant information:

- the default import is `\usepackage[backend=bibtex, sorting=none, bibstyle=ieee, natbib=true]{biblatex}`
- trying to `\usepackage{natbib}` results in a fatal compile error for some reason.
- I'm not using bibtex entries. Instead, all entries are `\bibitem{}`s. Maybe this is a terrible idea, but it's legacy and would be a huge pain to change now.
- So far I'm not using any .bib or .bbl files, I just use `\begin{thebibliography}{99}` at the end of each chapter, and place the `\bibitem`s there.

**Any help is greatly appreciated. Can provide more information if necessary.**

Comment: If your bibliography is written manually with `thebibliography` and `\bibitem`s (or if that structure is generated by a `.bst` file and BibTeX) you **cannot** use `biblatex`. `natbib` should work if all entries start with an optional argument giving the author and year (as in `\bibitem[Einstein(1915)]{GR_paper}`). If `natbib` produces an error, we need to see a short example document that reproduces the error (an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your bibliography is generated manually with `thebibliography` and `\bibitems` you absolutely *cannot* use `biblatex`. `biblatex` uses a completely different systems to produce citations and bibliography entries that is not compatible with `thebibliography` and `\bibitems`.

For you this is not of much interest, but it may be nice to know that when you use BibTeX with `\bibliographystyle` you are still using `thebibliography` and `\bibitem`. You just don't have to write them manually, BibTeX produces them for you from the `.bib` file (the argument of `\bibliography`) according to the specifications in the `.bst` file (the argument of `\bibliographystyle`). So everything that is said here about manual `thebibliography` also pretty much holds for BibTeX generated bibliographies.

So if you want to write your bibliography with `\bibitem` you have to remove `biblatex` from your preamble/template. Of course you then also need to remove all `biblatex`-related commands like `\addbibresource`, `\printbibliography`, `\defbibheading`, `\DeclareFieldFormat` ... from your document. If you are using a template, those commands could hide in multiple files. If you completely removed `biblatex` from your document, you may want to delete all temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, `.toc`, ...) to avoid problems with leftover `biblatex` commands in the auxiliary files.

It should, however, be perfectly possible to use `natbib` with manual `thebibliography`. If you want to use `natbib` with author-year citations, you need to provide author-year data via the optional argument of `\bibitem` as you already do in

```
\bibitem[Einstein(1915)]{GR_paper} Einstein, A. 1915. General Relativity.
```

see also [Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations (again!)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/552533/35864).

The following example  with `natbib` and manual `thebibliography` works absolutely fine.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\citep{GR_paper,sigfridsson}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem[Einstein(1915)]{GR_paper} Einstein, A. 1915. General Relativity.

\bibitem[Sigfridsson and Ryde(1998)]{sigfridsson} Sigfridsson, E. and Ryde, U. 1998.
  Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments.
  \emph{Journal of Computational Chemistry} 19(4): 377--395.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: Einstein, A. 1915. General Relativity.//Sigfridsson, E. and Ryde, U. 1998. Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. Journal of Computational Chemistry 19(4): 377–395.]