# Error in setting up referencing with Natbib plain style: \providecommand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, natbib, harvard-style

I've set up my referencing and it's worked perfectly before in this same format (Harvard style) for all citations and the bibliography, but when I added a new citation it threw my pdf ouput completely out of whack.

It works when I do this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}

This is an essay about \cite{clinch2006environmental} and \cite{aubert2019environmental}.

\bibliography{EnvironmentalEssay}
\end{document}
```

I get the output:

[image]

I want it in the Harvard style, so I changed to:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}

This is an essay about \citet{clinch2006environmental} and \citeyearpar{aubert2019environmental}.

\bibliography{EnvironmentalEssay}   
\end{document}
```

But then I suddenly get:

[image]

With the error: \providecommand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers "Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations"

And warning: that my author is undefined for first citation and year undefined for the second citation. I find this very strange though, since my Bibtex file is complete with all the information.

*EDIT: here is my Bibtex entries for the two sources:

```
@Article{aubert2019environmental,
  author    = {Aubert, Diane and Chiroleu-Assouline, Mireille},
  journal   = {European Economic Review},
  title     = {Environmental tax reform and income distribution with imperfect heterogeneous labour markets},
  year      = {2019},
  pages     = {60--82},
  volume    = {116},
  abstract  = {Text here xxx.},
  publisher = {Elsevier},
}

@Article{clinch2006environmental,
  author    = {Clinch, J Peter and Dunne, Louise and Dresner, Simon},
  journal   = {Energy Policy},
  title     = {Environmental and wider implications of political impediments to environmental tax reform},
  year      = {2006},
  number    = {8},
  pages     = {960--970},
  volume    = {34},
  abstract  = {text here xxxx.},
  publisher = {Elsevier},
}
```

It worked perfectly before for all commands:

```
\citep{}
\citet{}
\citeyearpar{}
etc.
```

However, since I added a new citation in my document, its producing errors.

I've tried changing the options on natbib, but nothing has worked. The time it worked perfectly I only had `\usepackage[round]{natbib}`.

*EDIT: I have tried using options `[authoryear,round]` option, but still has same outcome. I have now also changed the bibliographystyle from `{plain}` to `plainnat, with no success.

Please advise.

Comment: It's ok in the first case, so that suggests that `EnvironmentalEssay.bib` is ok, but it would be helpful if you posted that as well (with just those two references).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The `plain` bibliography style is not capable of generating authoryear-style citation call-outs; that's why changing `\cite` to `\citet` is causing problems. I suggest you (a) delete all aux files, (b) change `\bibliographystyle{plain}` to `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`, and (c) load `natbib` with the option `authoryear` (and `round`, if you so desire). Then, perform a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/552533/35864. As Mico said, `\bibliographystyle{plain}` is incompatible with `natbib`'s author-year citations. Changing to `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` is probably the easiest method.

Comment: Hi, I have tried changing the bibliography style to `{plainnat}' but still gave the same problem. I have updated the question and included my Bibtex for the two references.